# Update VSTO Excel Addin using Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, vsto, excel-addins

I have created a **VSTO Excel Addin** and deployed it via **Visual Studio Installer**. Now I want to update the deployed addin. I have tried to change **Product code**, **Upgrade code** & **version** in Project Properties of Visual Studio Installer Project but it does not update the installation. How i can update the installation ?

Answer (score 1):

You must **not change the upgrade code**, that will break your upgrade process.

You must increase the version and change the product code for a [major upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx). Read the linked MSDN article for more details.